# Outlook 365 - read only shared mailbox: how to force "send from" to default account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-interface, shared-mailbox

When forwarding or answering on items in the shared mailbox from is defaulted to the shared mailbox. Is there anyway to change this so it always defaults to send from my own mail account?

Tried to solve it with a VBA macro but `.SentOnBehalfOfName` did nothing.

The "message" ribbon has a button "from" which is can be toggled but it's on by default so I get these quite often:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/exchange/troubleshoot/shared-mailboxes/cannot-send-email-with-full-access

Comment: The email account displayed in "send from" depends on which email account you created the new message in. This is by design, so I'm afraid there is not a build-in way to change this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`MailItem.SendUsingAccount`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property.

Comment: I guess that the OP will understand this, because they (claim to) already know VBA.   But (as I expect that you know by now), our goal at Stack Exchange (Super User, etc.) is not just to help individual users, but to build a library (searchable knowledge base) of reusable answers.   You could make your answer more helpful to future readers by explaining *how* to use the MailItem.SendUsingAccount property.

Comment: @Scott, link to MS Docs shows help on this property and also the example on how to use it. Don't you think we need to copy-paste MSDN/Help/... articles here?

Comment: Um, yes, I share the widely held view that Stack Exchange/Super User answers should ***include*** (by copying) all necessary information and a reasonable amount of relevant information (while also linking to the source).  Microsoft, in particular, is notorious for removing or renaming useful web pages.  Don’t you know that link-only answers are routinely deleted here?  (Your answer probably isn’t at risk of that, since it does contain some actual information. If the link breaks, a future reader will at least know what to Google.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … But, yes, I believe you should explain how to use the MailItem.SendUsingAccount property — ideally, using your own words, but quoting from MSDN if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Once I get enough time to test this out I'll accept the answer